# Implementing C++ operator<< for a composite type

Tags: c++, io, operator-overloading, iostream

`operator<<(ostream&, T const&)` is the standard mechanism to support output of a type `T` object to a stream, and is commonly also used to convert a custom type to a string representation via `ostringstream` (although `to_string` appears to be also provided in C++11 for basic types).

For a simple single-data-member type, this is fairly straightforward:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Simple const& s)
{
    return str << s.value;
}
```

This allows the value to be output according to the stream's current rules -- ie. in the desired number format and with a specified width or padding.

As soon as you have a composite type which wishes to output multiple items, however, this becomes more complicated:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Complex const& c)
{
    return str << s.a << ':' << s.b;
}
```

At first glance, the above works as expected, and this seems to be the most common way to implement it, at least according to documentation.  But it's wrong.

Someone seeing Complex as a single value to be displayed and using `setw` to specify some justification for it will be surprised to discover that their width is entirely applied to the first component and not the "whole value".  And the class author might be surprised that sometimes their values are printed in hex.

So, maybe we should be outputting a single value to the original stream only?

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Complex const& c)
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << c.a << ':' << c.b;
    return str << s.str();
}
```

Firstly, it feels a bit wrong to turn a stream into a string and then poke it back at a stream (and requires additional memory allocation) -- but the other alternative of using `s.rdbuf()` instead doesn't work because it's treated as multiple separate insertions, once again applying the external `setw` in the wrong place.

Secondly, while now the external `setw` is handled as expected, it's been isolated from other settings on the stream, such as whether to display in hex or what locale to use.  Maybe this is a good thing in some cases, but it doesn't seem like the right thing to do generally.  It also still requires separate allocation of a temporary buffer.

Is there a preferred way of handling these sorts of things gracefully?

Comment: iostreams doesn't exactly have a reputation for being speedy and efficient. Constructing an intermediate `std::ostringstream`, and then dumping the end result as a single glob of chars is not going to make the existing situation much worse than it already is. If the complex object gets printed all the time, perhaps it's possible to cache the text implementation of the complex object as one of it's `std::string` members, and produce it upon demand.

Comment: One place to look could be the implementation of `std::complex`.

Comment: Ahaha I guess your string stream solution is good enough for libc++: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/complex#L1433 (edit: and libstdc++: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/complex#L528)

Comment: To clarify, I meant "Complex" as "more complicated than Simple", not as in the same meaning as `std::complex`.  But that's still an interesting comparison.